# Linq to sql update object

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a method in a datalibrary that looks like this

```
public IEnumerable<GeneralContractLine> getContractLines(int GeneralContractID)
{
    return db.GeneralContractLines.Where(l => l.FKGeneralContractID == GeneralContractID);
}

public void UpdateContractLine(GeneralContractLine line)
{
    //Update the object "line" 
}
```

The first method is ok, the db is just the datacontext object that is been initiliazied earlier.

The update method I would like to do something like:

```
db.GeneralContractLine.update(line);
db.submitChanges();
```

I know I can find the object, replace it then update, but are there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I can predict that you use the db object to get the GeneralContractLine object somewhere in your code and do some changes on it's properties and you want to save these updates so my solution for you is to just use the db.submitChanges() and all changes done on the GeneralContractLine object will be saved.

Comment: that depends on how the General Contract Line is changed, quite often with asp.net the item is disconnected from the data context so it doesn't save on submit changes

Comment: This happens in a diffent project. So I don't think I can just update the project. I'm trying to implement some kind of a repository pattern in a sepereate project.

Answer (score 0):

with Linq to SQL, you just change the object and then call SubmitChanges when you're done.

```
public void UpdateContractLine(GeneralContractLine line)
{
    //Update the object "line" 
    line.PropertyX = "Foo";
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: I would not like to change some properties in in, rather update/replace it. This code is in a dataAccess library and the call to the method can come from different front side systems. So the change of the property is already done when it comes to this repository class.

Comment: in that case, just call db.SubmitChanges().

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is create a extension method for the Table class for GeneralContractLine and add a method into it called Update().

Something Like

```
public static class LinqToSqlExtensions
{
    public static void Update(this System.Data.Linq.Table<GeneralContractLine> table, GeneralContractLine item)
    {
        var connectedItem = table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == item.ID);
        //Update logic in this case updating only the name
        connectedItem.Name = item.Name;
        table.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

just as a not, i have not tested any of this but it may be something that is worth trying

Oh and if it works, calling it should just be a case of adding a using statement to the namespace and then calling `db.GeneralContractLine.Update(line);`

Comment: Also if this works and you need to do it for multiple entities it might be possible to try a more generic version using <TEntity> and reflection